# How will a C++ template handle overflow?

Tags: c++, templates, types, overflow

I have implemented a template function "clamp" as my project does not support C++20.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr const T clamp(const T& value, const T& lo, const T& hi)
{
    return static_cast<T>(std::min(std::max(lo, value), hi));
}
```

I am using it to check for overflow in the following manner.

```
if (adcVal > clamp<uint16_t>((adcHi + voltageThreshold), adcHi, std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max()))
{
    //voltage has jumped past required threshold. 
}
```

Is there a guarantee that overflow value will remain as a `uint16_t`?

Comment: Don't take arguments by reference if they are simple integral values.

Comment: Assuming that `adcHi + voltageThreshold` does not overflow `uint16_t`, then yes. If there is overflow, you need to detect that separately. Your clamp function cannot detect this because `value` has already overflowed by the time it gets to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a guarantee that overflow value will remain as a uint16_t?

I suspect that you mean overflow in `adcHi + voltageThreshold`. I assume that the operands are `uint16_t`.

No, there is no such guarantee. On typical systems, the `uint16_t` operands will first be promoted to `int`, and the result will also be `int`. And it is possible for the sum to be outside the representable values of `uint16_t`.

Of course, once the result of the addition is converted to `uint16_t` when passed to `clamp`, it is guaranteed to be a `uint16_t`.

Passing `std::numeric_limits::max()` to clamp will mean that the input will not be clamped from the upper bound because it can never be greater than the limit.

> How will a C++ template handle overflow?

The overflow happens before the function template is called.

Comment: Yes, I am concerned with overflow in `adcHi + voltageThreshold` and the operands are both `uint16_t`.